# Why is calling `import random; random.random()` throwing a TypeError?

Tags: python-2.7, python-import

I'm new to Python. I wrote a small script to generate ten random float values, but it keeps failing. Here's the script:

```
import random

for i in range(10):
  x = random.random()
  print x
```

and here's the error message:

```
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable'.
```

I can't see what the problem is.
I'm pretty sure random exists!

My version is Python 2.7.6.

Comment: Are you sure this is the exact code causing the error?

Comment: With the script you've posted, I don't get the same error. I get a TypeError if I use `x = random()` instead of `x = random.random()`. Could that be the problem?

Comment: The code you posted works perfectly. Maybe the error occurs somewhere else in your code.

Comment: Now I understand my error. I put this script in a file named random.py Maybe Python get confused.

Comment: see [The name shadowing trap](http://python-notes.curiousefficiency.org/en/latest/python_concepts/import_traps.html#the-name-shadowing-trap).

Answer (score 1):

If you save the following code into `random.py`:

```
import random
print(__name__)
print(random)
print(random.random)
```

and run it then it prints something like:

```
random
<module 'random' from '/.../python/import/name-shadowing/random.py'>
<module 'random' from '/.../python/import/name-shadowing/random.py'>
__main__
<module 'random' from '/.../python/import/name-shadowing/random.py'>
<module 'random' from '/.../python/import/name-shadowing/random.py'>
```

i.e., both `random` and `random.random` refers to the same module -- your local `random.py` that shadows `random` module from the standard library.

Perhaps it works as follows:

1. `python -mrandom` finds `random.py` in the current directory, imports it as `random` and  and starts to run it as `__main__`.
2. It sees `import random` and imports the cached module.
3. `print(random)` prints the representation of the module object to stdout.
4. `print(random.random)` looks up `random` name in `random` module. It finds it (the name refers to the module itself. And it prints it.

The solution is to avoid shadowing the names. Avoid shadowing the standard names for readability. And avoid shadowing 3rd-party names if you might use them in your code.

If the current directory is not in `sys.path` then it imports stdlib module:

```
import sys
sys.path.pop(0) # assume the script directory is the first in the Python path
import random
print(__name__)
print(random)
print(random.random)
```

#### Output

```
__main__
<module 'random' from '/usr/lib/python3.4/random.py'>
<built-in method random of Random object at 0x1aaf7f8>
```

Note: it is only for illustration. Avoid modifying `sys.path` in your scripts.